# jest just passed all test even it is false

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, jestjs

I'm testing my vue.js app with jest.
and I realized that jest just passed all those test even it should be fail.
for example this one should be fail because input type password is true but all my test code passed either true or false. ..

```
  test('password input field type is password at the beginning', done => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const pw = wrapper.find({ ref: 'pw' });
      expect(pw.contains("[type='password']")).toBe(false);
    }, 10);
    done();
  });
```

```
beforeEach(() => {
  // Create the Store mock

  state = {
    auth: {
      something: false,

    },
    data: {},


  };
  getters = {
    somethingg: jest.fn(),

  };
  actions = {
    'auth/login': jest.fn(),

  };

  store = new Store({
    state,
    getters,
    actions
  });

  wrapper = shallowMount(TheLoginComponent, {
    propsData: {},
    mocks: {},
    stubs: {

    },
    methods: {

    },
    data: {},
    localVue,
    store
  });

});

afterEach(() => {
  wrapper.destroy();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setTimeout doesn't work with jest in this case. It's async and doesn't guarantee that it's executed before jests complete.

If you have async calls that makes you to write it, flushPromises like below and try:

`const flushPromises = new Promise(resolve=> setImmediate(resolve)) ;`

Inside tests :(note method is async)

`it('dummyTest', async() => {
          // Render here
          await flushPromises() ;
          //assert here
     }) ;`

Comment: thank you for your answer but could you please explain me where is the render part and assert part? because it keeps show me the error that flushPromises is not a function

Comment: @Erika I assume you already got and solved it? Render symolizes shallow/mount and assertion as in test assertions